# Передача значения в один из параметров функции по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Как можно упростить ниже приведенный код, чтобы сохранить функционал кода и обеспечить динамическую передачу `timeframeDigits` в один из параметров функции (`minutes, hours, days, weeks`) в зависимости от значения `timeframeLetter` ?

```
match(timeframeLetter):
    case 'm':
        scheduler.add_job(self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
                          minutes=timeframeDigits,
                          args=[strategyParams],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                          timezone='UTC')
    case 'h':
        scheduler.add_job(self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
                          hours=timeframeDigits,
                          args=[strategyParams],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                          timezone='UTC')
    case 'd':
        scheduler.add_job(self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
                          days=timeframeDigits,
                          args=[strategyParams],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                          timezone='UTC')
    case 'w':
        scheduler.add_job(self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
                          weeks=timeframeDigits,
                          args=[strategyParams],
                          start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                          timezone='UTC')
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы не гадать, примет ли api `None`, можно определить частично примененную функцию

```py
import functools

add_job = functools.partial(
    scheduler.add_job,
    self.processingStrategy,
    'interval',
    args=[strategyParams],
    start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
    timezone='UTC'
)

match timeframeLetter:
    case 'm':
        add_job(minutes=timeframeDigits)
    case 'h':
        add_job(hours=timeframeDigits)
    case 'd':
        add_job(days=timeframeDigits)
    case 'w':
        add_job(weeks=timeframeDigits)
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте что-то такое:

```py
scheduler.add_job(self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
                  minutes=timeframeDigits if timeframeLetter == 'm' else None,
                  hours=timeframeDigits if timeframeLetter == 'h' else None,
                  days=timeframeDigits if timeframeLetter == 'd' else None,
                  weeks=timeframeDigits if timeframeLetter == 'w' else None,
                  args=[strategyParams],
                  start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                  timezone='UTC')
```

В [документации](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) правда параметры по умолчанию стоят `undefined`, а не `None`, я не очень понимаю, что это, может это значение из этой библиотеки? Тогда нужно его вместо `None` поставить в этот код.

Comment: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/job.html?highlight=add_job#apscheduler.job.Job

Answer (score 3):

Вынесите повторяющийся код в отдельный метод, изменяющуюся часть передавайте как `kwargs`:

```
def add_job(self, strategyParams, **kwargs):
    scheduler.add_job(
        self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
        args=[strategyParams],
        start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
        timezone='UTC',
        **kwargs,
    )

...

    match(timeframeLetter):
        case 'm':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, minutes=timeframeDigits)
        case 'h':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, hours=timeframeDigits)
        case 'd':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, days=timeframeDigits)
        case 'w':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, weeks=timeframeDigits)
```

Можно явно перечислить все параметры, значения по умолчанию указать `None` (теоретически `schedule` должен воспринять это как незаполненный параметр, но нужно протестировать):

```
def add_job(self, strategyParams, minutes=None, hours=None, days=None, weeks=None):
    scheduler.add_job(
        self.processingStrategy, 'interval',
        args=[strategyParams],
        start_date='2000-01-01 00:00:00',
        timezone='UTC',
        minutes=minutes,
        hours=hours,
        days=days,
        weeks=weeks,
    )

...

    match(timeframeLetter):
        case 'm':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, minutes=timeframeDigits)
        case 'h':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, hours=timeframeDigits)
        case 'd':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, days=timeframeDigits)
        case 'w':
            self.add_job(strategyParams, weeks=timeframeDigits)
```

Comment: Кстати, хорошо, так код выглядит понятнее, чем в моём варианте )